# Why can ellipses be expressed as $y=Ax$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I am reading linear algebra textbook. One question is it said for vectors in the unit circle $||x||=1$. I can understand this. However, it said the vectors $y=Ax$ in the ellipse will have $||A^{-1}y||=1$. Why it is an ellipse?

I only know the ellipse can be expressed in this way:
$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $

Comment: note that a circle stretched in one direction becomes an ellipse

Comment: Consider a diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}$, then $Ax$ will turn the unit circle into the ellipse with axis lengths $a,b$.

Comment: How to stretch? Any matrix can stretch? or only diagonal matrix can stretch?

Comment: Some matrices stretch, some rotate, some do both, some do neither. Diagonal matrices specifically stretch _along the coordinate axes_ (vertically and horizontally).

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer: your formula for an ellipse holds if the (semi-minor and semi-major) axes of the ellipse are horizontal and vertical. More generally, the ellipses can point in any two perpendicular directions.

With that in mind, suppose that $\vec u,\vec v$ are orthogonal unit vectors. The component of $(x,y)$ along $\vec u = (u_1,u_2)$ is the dot-product $(u_1,u_2)\cdot (x,y) = \vec u \cdot \vec x$. We can produce the equation of an ellipse with axes in the direction of $u$ and $v$ by using the component of the vector $\vec x$ along $\vec u$ instead of the $x$-value and the component along $\vec v$ instead of the $y$-value. Doing this gives us the equation
$$
\frac{(\vec u \cdot \vec x)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(\vec v \cdot \vec x)^2}{b^2} = 1
$$
Now, let $M$ denote the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{u_1/a & u_2/a\\ v_1/b & v_2/b}.
$$
Verify that $M \vec x$ = $((\vec u\cdot \vec x)/a, (\vec v \cdot \vec x)/b)$. It follows that the equation of our ellipse is given by
$$
\|M \vec x\|^2 = 1 \implies \|M\vec x\| = 1.
$$
In other words, we see that every ellipse can be written in the form $\|M \vec x\| = 1$ for some matrix $M$.

---

The original question was why is it that $\|A^{-1}x\| = 1$ defines an ellipse for *every* (invertible) matrix $A$. So far, my question only answers this in the case that the rows of $A^{-1}$ happen to be orthogonal to each other.

One approach to answering this question is to combine our analysis above with the existence of the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: Yes, this is a problem from SVD. I can understand your u, v. I think in a more clear way, you mean b projects onto line u and line v. Since u, v are orthogonal, thus the 2 projections are $u^Tb$ and $v^Tb$. I do not quite understand your construction of matrix M.

Comment: What do you mean by "$b$ projects"? There is no vector $b$ in either your question or my answer.

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood you. In your 2nd paragraph, is (x,y) on the unit circle? What's the relationship between (x,y) and u, v?

Comment: $\vec x = (x,y)$ is a vector containing the coordinates of the point described by the equation for the ellipse. $\vec u \cdot \vec x$ and $\vec v \cdot \vec x$ are the components of $x$ along $\vec u, \vec v$, which is to say that 
$$
\vec x = (\vec u \cdot \vec x)\vec u + (\vec v \cdot \vec x) \vec v.
$$
For example, if $\vec u = (1,0)$ and $\vec v = (0,1)$, then we just have $\vec u \cdot \vec x  = x$ and $\vec v \cdot \vec x = y$.

Comment: I see. What is construction of M?

Comment: @christine $M$ is constructed so that
$$
M\vec x = \pmatrix{(\vec u \cdot \vec x)/a\\ (\vec v \cdot \vec x)/b} = \pmatrix{(u_1 x + u_2 y)/a\\ (v_1 x + v_2 y)/b}.
$$
This ensures that $\|M\vec x\|^2$ is the desired left side of the equation.